# Brightness Control AMD Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, brightness, radeon, amdgpu

Currently troubleshooting the following problem:

I have finally decided on a change in my life and I switched to Ubuntu 20.04 for my working computer. I own a Lenovo Thinkpad T14 AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 4750U, AMD Radeon Vega 7. I am facing the following problems:

1. After the fresh install, my monitor was not recognized in the monitors setting. It wrote "Unkown Display". I finally fixed that with installing the newest version of Radeon Drivers
   https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20
2. The problem that I am facing currently is that I cannot change the brightness from the screen. Neither via FN key nor via the control panel. Technically there is a workaround for this by installing brightness-controller. But it loses the sense of the FN keys

To my question:
After some research, I found out that the brightness control is fixed with Linux 5.8 Kernel. This kernel version has some nice features for AMD users (AMDGPU TMZ support, AMD Enegery Diver).

Is it a good idea to manually install the 5.8 version in order to fix those problems? I know that it is not officially supported by Ubuntu.

Or is there another fix for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a backup copy of the system using timeshift, should anything goes wrong after the kernel upgrade.

Comment: A relatively safe option is to try the 20.10 pre-release kernels here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/5.8.0-19.20 while you wait for 20.10.

Answer (score 1):

I have lenovo legion 5 ACH6H with RTX 3060 and Ryzen 5 5600H and had the same issue . Tried alot of drivers but nothing worked natively , fortunately you can use a utility name brightness control

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller

$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same GPU with my Ryzen 5 5500u and was facing the same problem.
I updated to the latest kernel and installed amd graphics drivers from their official site and after restarting, Kudos! It solved.

Comment: From which site did you download the drivers?